# No author information was supplied by the version control system

Tags: xcode, git, xcode10

I just updated my Xcode to **version 10.2** (10E125).

A moment I want to commit, I get this message:

[image]

After I click on fix:

[image]

I have filled in the information, but I’m still getting that message above.

What's the reason?

Comment: Use the command line instead?

Comment: @matt It would be lovely if we can use both (UI and command line)

Comment: I get the same error when trying to commit items (marked with a "!"), that does not exists on disk nor on server (I cannot discard items either). I do not get the error on files that exists.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can set the author information using Terminal. It might be possible that xCode has the author data but it's not actually set in Git config.

#### Setting your Git username for every repository on your computer

1) Open Terminal.

2) Set a Git username:

```
$ git config --global user.name "Mona Lisa"
```

3) Confirm that you have set the Git username correctly:

```
$ git config --global user.name
> Mona Lisa
```

#### Setting your Git username for a single repository

1) Open Terminal.

2) Change the current working directory to the local repository where you want to configure the name that is associated with your Git commits.

3) Set a Git username:

```
$ git config user.name "Mona Lisa"
```

4) Confirm that you have set the Git username correctly:

```
$ git config user.name
> Mona Lisa
```

Source: https://help.github.com/en/articles/setting-your-username-in-git

Answer (score 6):

Click on "Fix" and provide your Git username and email. This fixed my issue.

Comment: As you can see from the question, I also clicked on `FIX` and fill in the information. But the message re-appear once I want to commit again.

Comment: You may also need to add email info before Xcode will work:

    `git config user.email "email@example.com"`

or 

    `git config --global user.email "email@example.com"`

Answer (score 0):

If when you select "Fix" the info is already there:

- Erase it
- Attempt a commit
- Xcode will prompt you to "Fix" again
- Re-enter the info

That's the only thing that worked for me!